# Extending AsyncForwardingAppender in log4net

Tags: .net, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

Hi all I am trying to extend `AsyncForwardingAppender`.
I have the following config file:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="AsyncForwardingAppenderExtender" type="log4net.Async.AsyncForwardingAppender,Log4net.Async" >
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
    </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="Info" />
        <appender-ref ref="AsyncForwardingAppenderExtender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Now in my code I have overriden the `Append` method as follows

```
public class AsyncForwardingAppenderExtender : Log4Net.Async.AsyncForwardingAppender
{
    private Queue<LoggingEvent> buffer = new Queue<LoggingEvent>();
    private static readonly Type ThisType = typeof (AsyncForwardingAppender);

    public AsyncForwardingAppenderExtender()
    {
    }

    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        buffer.Enqueue(loggingEvent);
    }

    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent[] loggingEvents)
    {
        foreach (var loggingEvent in loggingEvents)
        {
            Append(loggingEvent);
        }
    }

    public override void ActivateOptions()
    {
        base.ActivateOptions();
        InitializeBuffer();
        StartForwarding();
    }

    private void StartForwarding()
    {
        Thread forwardingThread =
            new Thread(ForwardingThreadExecute)
            {
                Name = String.Format("{0} Forwarding Appender Thread", Name),
                IsBackground = false,
            };
        forwardingThread.Start();
    }

    public void InitializeBuffer()
    {
        buffer = new Queue<LoggingEvent>();
    }

    private void ForwardingThreadExecute()
    {
        try
        {
            ForwardLoggingEventsFromBuffer();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // ForwardInternalError("Unexpected error in asynchronous forwarding loop", exception, ThisType);
        }
    }

    private void ForwardLoggingEventsFromBuffer()
    {
        CLSAdapter adapter = new CLSAdapter();
        while (buffer.Count > 0)
        {
            LoggingEvent l = buffer.Dequeue();
            LoggingEventData data = l.GetLoggingEventData();
            adapter.CreateConnection(data.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

`Append` is appending to a queue. Then `StartForwading` pushes from the queue to Splunk through a function.

Problem is: `Append` is not getting triggered, when I do something like `Log.Fatal("hhhh")` from my program. What am I missing in creating this custom appender?

Comment: Does the same logging work with a default appender?

Answer (score 0):

```
<appender name="AsyncForwardingAppenderExtender" type="log4net.Async.AsyncForwardingAppender,Log4net.Async" >
```

the type is wrong - should be your AsyncForwardingAppenderExtender